# Android merger failed : don't want to change minSdkVersion for library's mindSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library, android-min-sdk

My Application is having minSdkVersion = 10. 
I would like to add a library which requires minSdkVersion to be more than 14, 
and hence I am getting Manifest merger failed error.

Is there any solution for it? 
Even if users having os version between 10-14 won't be able to use library's features is acceptible, 
but I want to give them access to app's other features.

Comment: use override attribute

Comment: Whatever you do, you won't be able to run the library under 14 without modification. If it really is a problem, maybe you should consider implementing the functions yourself with the older api.